# Prove that $\gamma$ is constant iff $\gamma′(t) = 0$ for all $t \in J$ if there is always an interval containing $t$ in which $ \gamma$ is const

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

I am trying to prove the following lemma.

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold
>
> (a) Let $J$ be an open interval and $ \gamma: J \to M$ a smooth curve. Suppose
> for every $t \in J$ there is an open interval $J_t \subseteq J$ with $t \in J_t$, on which $\gamma$ is constant. Prove that $\gamma $ is constant.
>
> (b) Prove that $\gamma$ is constant if and only if $\gamma′(t) = 0$ for all $t \in J$.

I have already proven (a), but I am having trouble with (b)

This is what I've done

$(\implies)$
If $\gamma $ is constant, then for every $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, $\gamma'(t)f=\frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \gamma)=0$. Since  $f \circ \gamma: J \subseteq \Bbb \to \Bbb R$ is a constant function, it follows from ordinary calculus that $f \circ \gamma(t)=0 \implies$ $\gamma'(t)f=0$. So $\gamma'(t)$ is the zero vector field on J.

$(\impliedby)$ I am stuck here. I think I have to take a chart, so that I can write the vector field in the basis $\{\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\right|_{\gamma(t)}, \dots,  \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right|_{\gamma(t)} \}$. (Here,  $n=\text{dim}M$.)

$$\gamma'(t)=\sum_{i+1}^{n}c_i(t)\left. \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_{\gamma(t)}=0$$

From $\gamma'(t)=0$, .I guess it follows that $c_i(t)=0$ for $i=1,...,n$

**My questions:**

**1. Is  $(\implies)$ correct?**

**2.  How do I prove $(\impliedby)$? Somehow I have to use part (a) there**

---

Edit:

Following the hints:

The third bullet in the answer below is proven like this:

The $a^i:J' \to \Bbb R$. Since $0=\gamma'(t)=\frac{d a^i(t)}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_{\gamma(t)} \implies \frac{d a^i(t)}{dt}=0 \implies  a^i(t)=$const for all $t \in J'$ , $i \in 1,...,n$. So we have that $\varphi \circ \gamma(t)=(a^1(t),...,a^n(t))=const$, for all $t \in J'$. Since $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism,we can compose with $\varphi^{-1}$ to get:
$\gamma(t)=\varphi^{-1}(t)\circ\varphi(t)\gamma(t)=\varphi^{-1}(const)=$const2 another constant, so we have that $\gamma$ is constant for all $t \in J'$.

But now putting together the result of the first and third bullet below we have show that for every $t_0 \in J$ there exists an interval $J'\subset S , t \in J'$ where $\gamma$ is constant. So now I can apply part (a) of my post to conclude that  $\gamma$ is constant in all of $J$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for $\implies$ looks fine.

For $\impliedby$, I agree that we should use part (a), and I also like the fact that you're thinking about how $\gamma$ looks in a chart. Here's a way to proceed.

- Pick any $t_0 \in J$, and let $(U, \varphi)$ be a coordinate chart on $M$ containing the point $\gamma(t_0)$. Using the *continuity* of $\gamma$, you can argue that there exists an open interval $J ' \subset J$ containing $t_0$ such that $\gamma(J') \subset U$.
- Now suppose that $\varphi \circ \gamma (t) = (a^1(t), \dots, a^n(t))$ is the coordinate representation of $\gamma$ with respect to the chart $(U, \varphi)$, valid for $t \in J'$. You should be able to write down an expression for $\gamma'(t)$ in terms of the tangent vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}|_{\gamma(t)},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}|_{\gamma(t)}$ and the time derivatives of $a^1(t), \dots, a^n(t)$. (This expression would be valid for $t \in J'$.)
- Having derived an expression for $\gamma'(t)$, you should be able to use calculus to show if $\gamma'(t)$ is zero for all $t$, then the functions $a^1(t), \dots, a^n(t)$ must all be constant functions.

Comment: How do we use the continuity of $\gamma$ in the first bullet? And where are we using (a)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do the second bullet?

Comment: On continuity of $\gamma$: Are you familiar with the definition of continuity based on open sets? What does that definition say?

Comment: On the second bullet point: The final answer should be $\gamma'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ a^i (t)}{dt} \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right|_{\gamma(t)}$. Can you see how to derive this? (In fact, this result might even be stated directly in your book / notes.)

Comment: On the use of (a): think about how you might prove the third bullet point.

Comment: The definition of continuity says that the preimage of an open set is an open set, but I don't see you are taking any preimage here, but an image. I am using Lee's book by the way

Comment: Since $\gamma $ is continuous, $\gamma^{-1}(U)$ is an open set containing $t$. Therefore, there exists an interval $J'$ such that $t \in J' \subset \gamma^{-1}(U)$. So $\gamma(J') \subset U$.

Comment: I have a proof if the third bullet, see my edit, does it look good?. I still don't know how to derive the expresion for $\gamma'(t)$ in the second bullet Could you show me how or point where in the book it is, I can't find it. I thought I could use that the coefficients of a vector field in a basis are the action of the vector field on the corresponding coordinate functions, so: $\gamma'(t)a^i(t)$ should be equal to $d a^i(t)/dt$ but I don't see how

Comment: I don't have Lee's book with me, but I'm 100% sure that this formula for $\gamma'(t)$ is in there. Look in the chapter on tangent vectors, and specifically the section on velocity vectors of curves.

Comment: Your method works too. If $x^i$ is the $i$th coordinate function, then $\gamma'(t)(x^i) = \frac{d(x^i\circ \gamma(t))}{dt} = \frac{d a^i(t)}{dt}$.

Comment: Could you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4813095/x-is-a-smooth-vector-field-on-m-x-0-iff-every-integral-curve-of-x-is-cons ?. It's the follow-up of this question