# $X$ is a smooth vector field on $M$. $X=0$ iff every integral curve of X is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to prove point c in this exercise:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold

(a) Let $J$ be an open interval and $ \gamma: J \to M$ a smooth curve. Suppose for every $t \in J$ there is an open interval $J_t \subseteq J$ with $t \in J_t$, on which $\gamma$ is constant. Prove that $\gamma $ is constant.

(b) Prove that $\gamma$ is constant if and only if $\gamma′(t) = 0$ for all $t \in J$.

**(c) Suppose that $X$ is a smooth vector field  on  $M$. Prove that
$X=0$ (i.e $X_p = 0 \in T_pM \forall p \in M$) iff every integral curve of $X$ is constant**

I have already proven (a) (b) here [Prove that $\gamma$ is constant iff $\gamma′(t) = 0$ for all $t \in J$ if there is always an interval containing $t$ in which $ \gamma$ is const](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812826/prove-that-gamma-is-constant-iff-gamma-t-0-for-all-t-in-j-if-there)

**My attempt**

$\implies$
Suppose $X=0$. Let $\gamma: J \to M $ be an integral curve of X, then $\gamma'(t)=X_{\gamma (t)}=0, \forall t \in J \implies $ From point (b) it follows that , $\gamma $ is constant

$\impliedby$
Suppose every integral curve of $X$ is constant. Let $p \in M$
Applying the following proposition
[image]

It follows that every point is the starting point of an integral curve of $X$,so $\exists \epsilon >0: \gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to M$ is an integral curve of  $X$ starting at $p$ ($\gamma(0)=p$). Then by assumption this integral curve is constant $\implies \gamma'(t)=0 \forall t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon )$. By definition of integral curve $\gamma'(t)=X_{\gamma(t)}=0 \forall t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon )$, In particular for $t=0:$ $\gamma'(0)=X_{\gamma(0)}=X_p=0$

Since $p$ was arbitrary, I have proven that $X=0$

**I would like some feedback on my solution. Is everything good?**

Comment: Yeah, looks good.